# Powershell Module variables don't work in exported functions but work in a single PS1 script

Tags: powershell

I recently added two functions into a PSM1. I noticed that the variables in the functions don't work right when I use the commands. However, they work FINE when I run the simple PS1 script alone. I added a verbose switch to the module to see the output. The output does not match the actual variable array itself. Please can you help me fix this?

```
Function Get-SystemUpdate {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [string]$path = $ENV:HOMEPATH + '\Documents',
    [string]$ComputerName = 'CORCFILGDC01',
    [ArgumentCompleter({
        param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete) # , $commandAst, $preBoundParameters omitted    
        $Forests = @('cfiorg.net', 'cfextranet.com', 'GROWHOW.LOCAL')
        foreach ($Forest in $Forests) {
          $dcs = @()
          $domains = (Get-ADForest -Identity $Forest).domains
          if ($domains -notlike '*cfiorg.net') {
            $dcs = @(foreach ($domain in $domains) {
                Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $domain -Discover -Service PrimaryDC | Select -ExpandProperty hostname
              })
            $dcs = ($dcs | % { $_.ToLower() })
          }
          else {
            $dcs = @(foreach ($domain in $domains) {
                Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $domain -Discover -Service PrimaryDC | Select -ExpandProperty Name
              })
            $dcs = $dcs
          }
          $dcall += $dcs
        }
        [array]$allPDCs = $dcall | sort
        $allPDCs -like "$wordToComplete*"
      })]
    [string]$DomainController = 'CORCFILGDC01',
    [switch]$saveOutput = $false,
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    $Credential = $local,
    [array]$HotFix = ('KB5031043', 'KB5031419')
  )
  # Get all Servers
  $computers = @()
  $n = 0
  $computers = @(Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$computerName'" -Properties * -Server $domainController -ResultSetSize 500 -Credential $Credential)
  $inLine = @()
  $duzit = 'CF3' + (Get-Date -format 'yyMMdd')
  $file = $duzit + ' - SysUpdates-' + $domainController + '.xlsx'
  $startTime = Get-Date
  Write-Verbose ("Systems found: '" + $ComputerName + "'")
  Write-Progress -Completed -Activity 'Completed'
  # Loop through
  foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $present = 'N/A'
    $n++
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $HotFix.Length; $i++) {
      $current = $HotFix[$i]
      $connection = ''
      $name = $computer.Name
      #$name = $computer
      $WinRM = 'N/A'
      $OS = $computer.OperatingSystem
      $IP = $computer.IPv4Address
      $Build = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $name).Version
      $p1sequence = [string]$i + '/' + [string]$counter
      $elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $startTime
      $elapsedTime = $elapsedTime.Minutes
      $connection = Get-Connection -Server $name
      $WinRM = if ($connection -eq 'Yes') { Get-WinRM -Server $name } else { $WinRM = 'N/A' }
      $RegValue = if ($WinRM -eq 'Yes') { Get-RegValue -Server $name } else { $RegValue = 'N/A' }
      #$global:error.Clear()
      $out = [ordered]@{
        Name       = $name
        Connection = $connection
        RegValue   = $RegValue
        OS         = $OS
        IP         = $IP
        Build      = $Build
        WinRM      = $WinRM
      }
      foreach ($fix in $HotFix) {
        if ($fix -eq $current) {
          $global:error.Clear()
          if ($connection -eq 'Yes') {
            $present = 'N/A'
            try { Get-HotFix -Id $fix -ComputerName $name -ErrorAction Stop }
            catch { if ($global:error -like '*Cannot find the requested hotfix*') { $present = 'No' } else { $present = 'WinRM Error' } }
            if (!$global:error) { $present = 'Yes' }
            Write-Verbose ('ComputerName: ' + $name)
            Write-Verbose ($fix + ': ' + $present)
          }
        }
        $out[$fix] = $present
        continue
      }
      #$out[$fix] = ''
      $p1sequence = [string]$n + '/' + [string]$counter
      Write-Verbose ('Connection: ' + $connection)
      Write-Verbose ('WinRM: ' + $WinRM)                    
      #Write-Verbose ($($name)+": "+$p1sequence)
      Write-Verbose ('Elapsed Time: ' + $([string]$elapsedTime) + ' Minutes')
      Write-Verbose ('----')
    }
    [pscustomobject]$out
    [PSCustomObject]$inLine += [PSCustomObject]$out
  }
  if ($saveOutput -eq $true) {
    Import-Module ImportExcel
    $inLine | Export-Excel -Path ($path + '\' + $file) -WorksheetName $domainController -AutoSize -AutoFilter
    Write-Host 'FILE SAVED: ' $path"\"$file
  }
  else {
    #$inLine #|Export-Csv -Path ($path +"\" + $file) -NoTypeInformation
  }
  Write-Verbose ([string]$startTime + ' (Run time: ' + [string]$elapsedTime + ' Minutes)')
}
Function Get-SystemUpdates {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param (
    [string]$path = $ENV:HOMEPATH + '\Documents',
    [string]$operatingSystem = 'Windows Server',
    [ArgumentCompleter({
        param($commandName, $parameterName, $wordToComplete) # , $commandAst, $preBoundParameters omitted    
        $Forests = @('cfiorg.net', 'cfextranet.com', 'GROWHOW.LOCAL')
        foreach ($Forest in $Forests) {
          $dcs = @()
          $domains = (Get-ADForest -Identity $Forest).domains
          if ($domains -notlike '*cfiorg.net') {
            $dcs = @(foreach ($domain in $domains) {
                Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $domain -Discover -Service PrimaryDC | Select -ExpandProperty hostname
              })
            $dcs = ($dcs | % { $_.ToLower() })
          }
          else {
            $dcs = @(foreach ($domain in $domains) {
                Get-ADDomainController -DomainName $domain -Discover -Service PrimaryDC | Select -ExpandProperty Name
              })
            $dcs = $dcs
          }
          $dcall += $dcs
        }
        [array]$allPDCs = $dcall | sort
        $allPDCs -like "$wordToComplete*"
      })]
    [string]$DomainController = 'CORCFILGDC01',
    [switch]$saveOutput = $false,
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    $Credential = $local,
    [array]$HotFix = ('KB5031043', 'KB5031419')
  )
  # Get all Servers
  $filter = "'*" + $operatingSystem + "*'"
  $computers = @()
  $n = 0
  Write-Verbose ('.')
  Write-Verbose ('..')
  Write-Verbose ('...')
  #Write-Verbose "Gathering computer data..."
  Write-Verbose ("The filter you used: '" + $operatingSystem + "'")
  [int]$counter = (Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingSystem -like $filter" -Server $domainController -ResultSetSize 500 -Credential $Credential).Count
  [int]$s = 0
  $computers = @(Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingSystem -like $filter" -Properties * -Server $domainController -ResultSetSize 500 -Credential $Credential)
  #[int]$count = $computers.Length
  #$computers = @("CFRADIUS","CFLDSQL4","CFFILE4","CFFILE5")
  Get-ADComputer -Filter "operatingSystem -like $filter" -Properties * -Server $domainController -ResultSetSize 500 -Credential $Credential | % {
    $s++
    $computers += $_
    Write-Progress -Activity ('Processing Computers [' + $s + '/' + $counter + '] : ' + $_.Name) -PercentComplete ($s / $counter * 100) -CurrentOperation $counter[$_]
  }
  $inLine = @()
  $duzit = 'CF3' + (Get-Date -format 'yyMMdd')
  $file = $duzit + ' - SysUpdates-' + $domainController + '.xlsx'
  $startTime = Get-Date
  Write-Verbose ("Systems found: '" + $counter + "'")
  Write-Progress -Completed -Activity 'Completed'
  # Loop through
  foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $n++
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $HotFix.Length; $i++) {
      $current = $HotFix[$i]
      $connection = ''
      $name = $computer.Name
      #$name = $computer
      $WinRM = 'N/A'
      $OS = $computer.OperatingSystem
      $IP = $computer.IPv4Address
      $Build = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $name).Version
      $p1sequence = [string]$i + '/' + [string]$counter
      $elapsedTime = $(get-date) - $startTime
      $elapsedTime = $elapsedTime.Minutes
      $connection = Get-Connection -Server $name
      $WinRM = if ($connection -eq 'Yes') { Get-WinRM -Server $name } else { $WinRM = 'N/A' }
      $RegValue = if ($WinRM -eq 'Yes') { Get-RegValue -Server $name } else { $RegValue = 'N/A' }
      $global:error.Clear()
      $out = [ordered]@{
        Name       = $name
        Connection = $connection
        RegValue   = $RegValue
        OS         = $OS
        IP         = $IP
        Build      = $Build
        WinRM      = $WinRM
      }
      foreach ($fix in $HotFix) {
        if ($fix -eq $current) {
          $global:error.Clear()
          if ($connection -eq 'Yes') {
            try { Get-HotFix -Id $fix -ComputerName $name -ErrorAction Stop }
            catch { if ($global:error -like '*Cannot find the requested hotfix*') { $present = 'No' } else { $present = 'WinRM Error' } }
            if (!$global:error) { $present = 'Yes' }
            $global:error.Clear()
            Write-Verbose ('ComputerName: ' + $name)
            Write-Verbose ($fix + ': ' + $present)
            #$out[$fix] = $present
          }
        }
        $out[$fix] = $present
        continue
      }
      #$out[$fix] = $present
      $p1sequence = [string]$n + '/' + [string]$counter
      Write-Verbose ('Connection: ' + $connection)
      Write-Verbose ('WinRM: ' + $WinRM)                    
      Write-Verbose ($($name) + ': ' + $p1sequence)
      Write-Verbose ('Elapsed Time: ' + $([string]$elapsedTime) + ' Minutes')
      Write-Verbose ('----')
    }
    [pscustomobject]$out
    [PSCustomObject]$inLine += [PSCustomObject]$out
  }
  if ($saveOutput -eq $true) {
    Import-Module ImportExcel
    $inLine | Export-Excel -Path ($path + '\' + $file) -WorksheetName $domainController -AutoSize -AutoFilter
    Write-Host 'FILE SAVED: ' $path"\"$file
  }
  else {
    $inLine #|Export-Csv -Path ($path +"\" + $file) -NoTypeInformation
  }
  Write-Verbose ([string]$startTime + ' (Run time: ' + [string]$elapsedTime + ' Minutes)')
}
Function Get-AllDomainControllers {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credential,
    [ValidateSet('PDC', 'RID', 'Infrastructure', 'Naming', 'Schema')][string]$Role = 'None'
  )
  $domains = (Get-ADForest).domains
  $dcs = foreach ($domain in $domains) { Get-ADDomainController -Discover -DomainName $domain }
  switch ($Role) {
    'None' {
      $result = foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
        $ForestMode = (Get-ADForest -Credential $Credential).ForestMode
        $DomainMode = (Get-ADDomain -Server $dc -Credential $Credential).DomainMode
        Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $dc -Credential $Credential | select Name, HostName, IPv4Address, Domain, OperatingSystem, @{Name = 'DomainMode'; Expression = { $DomainMode } }, @{Name = 'ForestMode'; Expression = { $ForestMode } }, IsGlobalCatalog, OperationMasterRoles, Site, ServerObjectGuid
      }
    }
    'PDC' {
      $result = foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
        $DomainMode = (Get-ADDomain -Server $dc -Credential $Credential).DomainMode
        Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $dc -Credential $Credential | ? { $_.OperationMasterRoles -match 'PDCEmulator' } | select Name, HostName, IPv4Address, Domain, OperatingSystem, @{Name = 'DomainMode'; Expression = { $DomainMode } }, IsGlobalCatalog, OperationMasterRoles, Site, ServerObjectGuid
      }
    }
    'RID' {
      $result = foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
        $DomainMode = (Get-ADDomain -Server $dc -Credential $Credential).DomainMode
        Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $dc -Credential $Credential | ? { $_.OperationMasterRoles -match 'RIDMaster' } | select HostName, IPv4Address, Domain, OperatingSystem, @{Name = 'DomainMode'; Expression = { $DomainMode } }, IsGlobalCatalog, OperationMasterRoles, Site, ServerObjectGuid
      }
    }
    'Infrastructure' {
      $result = foreach ($dc in $dcs) {
        $DomainMode = (Get-ADDomain -Server $dc -Credential $Credential).DomainMode
        Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $dc -Credential $Credential | ? { $_.OperationMasterRoles -match 'InfrastructureMaster' } | select Name, HostName, IPv4Address, Domain, OperatingSystem, @{Name = 'DomainMode'; Expression = { $DomainMode } }, IsGlobalCatalog, OperationMasterRoles, Site, ServerObjectGuid
      }
    }
    'Naming' {
      $ForestMode = (Get-ADForest -Credential $Credential).ForestMode
      $result = foreach ($dc in $dcs) { Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $dc -Credential $Credential | ? { $_.OperationMasterRoles -match 'DomainNamingMaster' } | select Name, HostName, IPv4Address, Domain, OperatingSystem, @{Name = 'ForestMode'; Expression = { $ForestMode } }, IsGlobalCatalog, OperationMasterRoles, Site, ServerObjectGuid }
    }
    'Schema' {
      $SchemaServer = (Get-ADForest -Credential $Credential).SchemaMaster
      $ForestMode = (Get-ADForest -Credential $Credential).ForestMode
      $SchemaVersion = Get-ADObject (Get-ADRootDSE).schemaNamingContext -Property objectVersion -Server $SchemaServer -Credential $Credential
      $result = foreach ($dc in $dcs) { Get-ADDomainController -Filter * -Server $dc -Credential $Credential | ? { $_.OperationMasterRoles -match 'SchemaMaster' } | select Name, HostName, IPv4Address, Domain, OperatingSystem, @{Name = 'SchemaVersion'; Expression = { $SchemaVersion.objectVersion } }, @{Name = 'ForestMode'; Expression = { $ForestMode } }, IsGlobalCatalog, OperationMasterRoles, Site, ServerObjectGuid }
    }
  }
  $result
}
function Get-Connection($Server) {
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Quiet -ErrorAction Stop) { $connection = 'Yes' }
  else { $connection = 'No' }
  return $connection
}
function Get-WinRM($Server) {
  if (Test-WsMan -ComputerName $name) { $WinRM = 'Yes' } else { $WinRM = 'No' }
  return $WinRM
}
function Get-RegValue($Server) {
  try { $RegValue = @(Invoke-Command -ComputerName $name { Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name BuildLabEx }) }
  catch { $RegValue = 'WinRM Error' }
  return $RegValue.BuildLabEx
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function Get-SystemUpdate, Get-SystemUpdates
```

Here is a sample of the output with Verbose

```
Import-Module .\SystemUpdates\SystemUpdates.psm1 -Verbose -PassThru
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Scripts\gitScripts\echatham\Priv_CF\Modules\SystemUpdates\SystemUpdates.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-SystemUpdate'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-SystemUpdates'.

ModuleType Version    PreRelease Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ---------- ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0                   SystemUpdates                       {Get-SystemUpdate, Get-SystemUpdates}
Get-SystemUpdate -ComputerName CFWEC1 -domainController CORCFILGDC01 -saveOutput:$false -HotFix "KB5035855","KB5035849","KB5035857" -Credential $local -Verbose
VERBOSE: Systems found: 'CFWEC1'

Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
CFWEC1        Security Update  KB5035855     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  3/17/2024 00:00:00
VERBOSE: ComputerName: CFWEC1
VERBOSE: KB5035855: Yes
VERBOSE: Connection: Yes
VERBOSE: WinRM: Yes
VERBOSE: Elapsed Time: 0 Minutes
VERBOSE: ----
VERBOSE: ComputerName: CFWEC1
VERBOSE: KB5035849: No
VERBOSE: Connection: Yes
VERBOSE: WinRM: Yes
VERBOSE: Elapsed Time: 0 Minutes
VERBOSE: ----
VERBOSE: ComputerName: CFWEC1
VERBOSE: KB5035857: No
VERBOSE: Connection: Yes
VERBOSE: WinRM: Yes
VERBOSE: Elapsed Time: 0 Minutes
VERBOSE: ----

Name       : CFWEC1
Connection : Yes
RegValue   : 14393.6795.amd64fre.rs1_release.240226-1752
OS         : Windows Server 2016 Standard
IP         : 10.4.9.255
Build      : 10.0.14393
WinRM      : Yes
KB5035855  : No
KB5035849  : No
KB5035857  : No

VERBOSE: 03/27/2024 10:49:43 (Run time: 0 Minutes)
```

Comment: "don't work right" and "works FINE" tell us little about what you're _expecting_ to happen. Which variable doesn't have the value you expect, and what is the exact effect?

Comment: Hello, for example, look at "KB5035855" in the Verbose versus the actual variable output $inLine. They don't match. That server does have the patch (verbose is correct) but it doesn't reflect in the actual output.